# Why is a refresh needed to load new route with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using create-react-app and my routes doesn't load unless I refreshed the page first.

Does that have something to do with `historyFallbackApi: true` inside of webpack's config?

here's the code.

```
 const AppRouter = () => {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Chatbot} />
          <Route  path = "/about" component = {About} />
        </Router>
      );
    };

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <AppRouter />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: are your `Link` components inside NavBar?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Mohammed! Your `Link` components need to be inside of the `Router` component as well, or they will not get the correct `history` object through context.

Comment: It is, but I'm using NavLink not Link 

I surrounded the whole Navbar component with the Router 
but still having the same problem